# Angular router active link based only on 1st route level

Tags: angular, angular-router

I have link to offer list on top of my website that goes to `/offer/list` on that page with the list user can click on any offer and go to `/offer/detail?offer=1`.

What I want is that no matter if user is on list or detail, I want to see offer link active.

Currently, my code is following and adds `.active` class only on `/offer/list` page and it doesn't work. Any ideas how to fix it, please?

```html
<li class="nav-item"
 <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/offer/list']"
  [class.active]="router.isActive('/offer', false)"
  routerLinkActive="active">
   Offer Regions
 </a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe you can try something like this:

```
<li class="nav-item"
 <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/offer/list']"
  [class.active]="router.url.startsWith('/offer')"
  routerLinkActive="active">
   Offer Regions
 </a>
</li>
```

I think this will give the desired result.